# How do I display ngFor data outside of ngFor loop angular?

Tags: html, angular, ngfor

I have two ngFor loops in my component.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let x of xs; let i = index">
    <ng-template #printData>
      <p>
        <span>Test</span>
      </p>
    </ng-template>
    <p>
      <span>{{x}}</span>
    </p>
    <!-- Iterate ys-->
    <ng-container *ngFor="let y of ys[i]; let j = index">
      <ng-container *ngIf="j==0 && y?.value; else normalPrintData">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="printData"></ng-container>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-template #normalPrintData>
         <p *ngIf="y?.value">
            <span>Test</span>
         </p>
      </ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

basically I have two for loops but I want to display printData above the normal "x" interpolation if some condition is satisfied. I tried using ngTemplateOutlet but that does not work because the template is just printed at the ng-container that its called from.

Using an ngIf works but I feel a better solution can be achieved. Please help.

Comment: Please provide a stackblitz with the issue and screenshot of expected output!

Answer (score 0):

How about using ng-template [context](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet) and setting the `x` property.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let x of xs; let i = index">
    <ng-template #printData>
      <p>
        <span>{{x}}</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <span>Test</span>
      </p>
    </ng-template>
    <!-- Iterate ys-->
    <ng-container *ngFor="let y of ys[i]; let j = index">
      <ng-container *ngIf="j==0 && y?.value; else normalPrintData">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="printData; context: {x}"></ng-container> <!-- <------ changed here -->
      </ng-container>
      <ng-template #normalPrintData>
         <p *ngIf="y?.value">
            <span>Test</span>
         </p>
      </ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: xs is from the first loop, I want test to print above the {{x}}